# How to update a text block and progress bar from a different ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am trying to figure out how to update a progress dialog box from a separate ViewModel. This is my first full C# application, and in actuality, my first application. I have been stuck on this particular issue for a couple of days now, and feel that I have tried to approach it from a couple of different angles, but with no success.

Let's start with a brief overview: This application will be used by myself and my team to assist in staging PC's for deployment in the field. It starts with a very simple UI where the staging tech will select the site ID from a list and then click on "Configure" to start the process. The rest of the process will not require any user interaction.

I am trying to have a progress dialog box appear on top of the initial UI to give the tech an indication of the progress.

At the moment, I am able to get the progress box to appear, but am not able to update it.

Here is the code for the ShellViewModel:

```
namespace StagingWpfUI.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<ConfigureServerEvent>, IHandle<LoadDeviceInfoEvent>
    {
        #region Private Variables

        private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
        private readonly ProgressDialogViewModel _progressVM;
        private readonly DeviceInfoViewModel _deviceInfoVM;
        private readonly IWindowManager _window;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator events,
                              IWindowManager window,
                              ProgressDialogViewModel progressVM,
                              DeviceInfoViewModel deviceInfoVM)
        {
            _events = events;
            _progressVM = progressVM;
            _deviceInfoVM = deviceInfoVM;
            _window = window;
            _events.SubscribeOnUIThread(this);

            ActivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<DeviceConfigureViewModel>(), new CancellationToken());
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public async Task HandleAsync(ConfigureServerEvent message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //await ActivateItemAsync(_progress);
            dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();

            settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            settings.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            settings.Title = "Progress";
            settings.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

            await DeactivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<DeviceConfigureViewModel>(), true, new CancellationToken());

            await _window.ShowWindowAsync(_progressVM, null, settings);
        }

        public async Task HandleAsync(LoadDeviceInfoEvent message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await DeactivateItemAsync(_deviceInfoVM, true);
        }

        #endregion
```

The DeviceConfigureViewModel (main UI), is activated when the application starts. The ProgressDialogVM is called when the ConfigureServer method is called from the DeviceConfigureVM. That works fine. But when I try to do any work, the progress does not update.

Here is the code for the ProgressDialogView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StagingWpfUI.Views.ProgressDialogView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Background="LightBlue"
        d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="650">
    <Grid Margin="20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="ProgressMessage" Text="This is a test message" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 10" Style="{StaticResource ProgressMessage}"/>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="StagingProgress" Height="25" Width="600" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentProgress}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the ProgressDialogViewModel:

```
namespace StagingWpfUI.ViewModels
{
    public class ProgressDialogViewModel : Screen
    {
        private int _currentProgress;
        private string _progressMessage;

        public int CurrentProgress
        {
            get => _currentProgress;
            set
            {
                _currentProgress = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentProgress);
            }
        }

        public string ProgressMessage
        {
            get => _progressMessage;
            set
            {
                _progressMessage = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProgressMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the ConfigureServer method, I am calling the ConfigureServerEvent like this:

```
await _events.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new ConfigureServerEvent());
```

And then moving into a separate private method, Configure:

```
private void Configure(StagingModel model)
        {
            string csvPath = Path.Combine(_scriptPath, _sitesCsv);
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(_scriptPath, "staging.csv");

            _fileHelper.DeleteMarkerFile("first", "first.done");

            SiteModel siteModel = _textHelper.GetSiteModelByID(model.SiteId, csvPath);

            siteModel.StagingTech = model.StagingTech;

            //GetStagingFiles(siteModel.SiteID);

            if (model.HDReplacement == 0)
            {
                _logger.Info("Full server replacement selected...");
                FullServerReplacement(siteModel);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Info("Hard drive replacement selected...");

                if (model.HDLetter.ToLower() == "c:")
                {
                    _logger.Info("C: drive replacement selected...");
                    CDriveReplacement(siteModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Info("D: drive replacement selected...");
                    DDriveReplacement(siteModel);
                }
            }

            _logger.Info($"Writing site info for site { siteModel.SiteID } to CSV file...");

            List<SiteModel> siteList = new List<SiteModel> { siteModel };
            _textHelper.WriteToCsv(siteList, outputFile, false);
        }
```

The method finally implements `Progress` and the ProgressChanged event is called FullServerReplacement:

```
private void FullServerReplacement(SiteModel model)
        {
            Progress<ProgressReportModel> progress = new Progress<ProgressReportModel>();
            progress.ProgressChanged += Progress_ProgressChanged;

            StageMachine(model, progress);
        }
```

Finally, in the StageMachine method, I am "trying" to report on the progress:

```
   private void StageMachine(SiteModel site, IProgress<ProgressReportModel> progress)
    {
        ProgressReportModel report = new ProgressReportModel();

        _logger.Info("***************************Stage Machine selected.***************************");
        report.ProgressMessage = "Beginning staging...";
        report.CurrentProgress = 0;
        progress.Report(report);
        // Do more work and report the progress
```

But, no matter what I've tried, I cannot get the dialog to update. Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Basically what you need to understand : WPF has a single UI Thread that updates elements based on the request queue. Keeping that in mind it is not difficult to create a update between viewmodels (easiest and simplest way to have a manager/service that keeps track of the application and exchange/implements a messaging system). Based on provided code, you are using some libs, so I would suggest to see the docs if they have already messaging system already implemented, so that different viewmodels can exchange information

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal repo of your issue? Where are your example calling `FullServerReplacement`? And what are you doing while the dialog window is shown?

Comment: @mm8: I edited the question with the code for the `Configure` method which then calls `FullServerReplacement`.  As for what is being done while the dialog is shown: changing computer name, setting time zone, setting environment variables, modifying INI's and XML's, installing and uninstalling programs, etc.

Comment: Are you doing this on a background thread?

Comment: @mm8: No. I'm pretty sure I need to, though I haven't been able to figure out how to pass the current thread to the background thread.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `ProgressReportModel` in `StageMachine`. How is the original one being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this, I finally figured it out.

Initially, I was trying to use `Progress()` and `IProgress<T>`, which isn't the way you do it in Caliburn Micro. It's done through event aggregation. I just had to work through how and where to call the event. Thanks to @Demon for pointing me in the right direction on that.

The `UpdateProgressEvent` class:

```
public class UpdateProgressEvent
    {
        public UpdateProgressEvent(ProgressReportModel report)
        {
            _progressReport = report;
        }

        private ProgressReportModel _progressReport;

        public ProgressReportModel ProgressReport => _progressReport;
    }
```

One of the big issues was I wasn't subscribed to the event in the correct ViewModel. I subscribed to the `UpdateProgressEvent` in the `ProgressDialogViewModel` and then updated the progress in the `Handle` method:

```
 public class ProgressDialogViewModel : Screen, IHandle<UpdateProgressEvent>
    {
        public ProgressDialogViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
        {
            _events = events;
            _events.SubscribeOnUIThread(this);
        }

        private int _currentProgress;
        private string _progressMessage;
        private readonly IEventAggregator _events;

        public int CurrentProgress
        {
            get => _currentProgress;
            set
            {
                _currentProgress = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentProgress);
            }
        }

        public string ProgressMessage
        {
            get => _progressMessage;
            set
            {
                _progressMessage = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProgressMessage);
            }
        }

        public Task HandleAsync(UpdateProgressEvent message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            UpdateProgress(message.ProgressReport.Progress, message.ProgressReport.Message);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void UpdateProgress(int val, string msg)
        {
            ProgressMessage = msg;
            CurrentProgress = val;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProgressMessage);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentProgress);
        }
    }
```

I modified the `ProgressDialogView` slightly:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="ProgressMessage" Text="This is a test"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 10" Style="{StaticResource ProgressMessage}"/>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="CurrentProgress" Height="25" Width="600" IsIndeterminate="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

The big difference was I had to run the `Configure` method on a separate thread, as mentioned by @mm8:

```
public async Task ConfigureServer()
    {
        _logger.Info("Starting to configure server...");

        int hdReplacement = 0;
        if (SelectedHDReplacement.ToLower() == "yes")
        {
            hdReplacement = 1;
        }

        StagingModel staging = new StagingModel
        {
            SiteId = SelectedSiteID,
            StagingTech = TechName,
            HDReplacement = hdReplacement,
            HDLetter = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectedHDLetter) ? null : SelectedHDLetter
        };

        await _events.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new ConfigureServerEvent());

        await Task.Run(() => Configure(staging));
    }
```

Then, inside the `StageMachine` method:

```
        public async void StageMachine(SiteModel site)
    {
        ProgressReportModel progress = new ProgressReportModel();

        _logger.Info("***************************Stage Machine selected.***************************");
        progress.Message = "Stage machine selected...";
        progress.Progress = 0;
        await _events.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new UpdateProgressEvent(progress));
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        //string iberdir = _serverHelper.GetEnvironmentVariable("IBERDIR");

        _logger.Info("Setting computer name...");
        progress.Message = "Setting computer name...";
        progress.Progress = 5;
        await _events.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(new UpdateProgressEvent(progress));
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        //ServerHelper.SetComputerName(site.ServerName);
        // Do more work here.
```

The `Thread.Sleep()` is just for testing as I'm commenting out the actual work being done, but it simulates a longish running task.

But now it is working.

Thanks